# Points changing sizes on ggplot geom_point and no legend?

Tags: r, ggplot2, maps, ggmap

Okay so here is my code for a base map:

```
gg <- ggmap(Peru) +
  geom_map(data = peru.coast, map = peru.coast, aes(x = long, y = lat, map_id = region),
           fill="gray", color="black") +
  xlim(-86, -70) +
  ylim(-20, -4) + 
  labs(x = "Longitude", y = "Latitude") +
  coord_map()
```

I then add in towns I wish to name manually (wasn't sure how to do it using google maps as I only wanted these 4)

```
gg <- gg + geom_point(aes(x=-78.981885, y=-8.229354, size=3)) +
  annotate("text", label='Salaverry', size=4, x=-77.2, y=-8.229354) +
  geom_point(aes(x=-71.345838, y=-17.644347, size=3)) +
  annotate("text", x=-70.545838, y=-17.644347, label = 'Ilo', size=4) +
  geom_point(aes(x=-77.142375, y=-12.047544, size=3)) +
  annotate("text", x=-75.9, y=-12.047544, label = 'Callao', size=4) +
  geom_point(aes(x=-78.610677, y=-9.074166, size=3)) +
  annotate("text", x=-76.9, y=-9.074166, label = 'Chimbote', size=4)
gg <- gg + guides(size=FALSE) #this removes the legend with the black dot and '3' on it 
gg
```

I get this lovely map:
[image]

I then use this dataset to add datapoints, and I wish to make the points bigger or smaller according to 'n' abundance

```
Trip_Set sex        Set.Lon     Set.Lat     n
119_1    hembra -81.09390   -9.32338    2
119_7    hembra -81.03117   -9.09622    1
161_3    macho  -83.76533   -9.74533    5
193_8    hembra -81.00888   -9.00950    7
255_5    macho  -80.14992   -8.64592    1
271_6    hembra -72.20233   -18.05117   6
271_6    macho  -72.20233   -18.05117   7
328_7    hembra -78.66667   -12.91700   2
403_3    hembra -80.03037   -10.03900   1
428_2    hembra -83.01305   -8.74883    2
655_4    hembra -71.58363   -18.24882   1
```

using this code:

```
ggAB <- gg + geom_point(data=dframe4, aes(Set.Lon, Set.Lat, colour='red', size=n)) 
ggAB <- ggAB + theme(legend.title = element_text(colour="black", size=12, face="bold")) 
ggAB <- ggAB +  guides(colour=FALSE) #This removes the legend for the red colour
ggAB <- ggAB +  scale_size(name='Sharks per line', range = c(5,9)) 
ggAB <- ggAB +  theme(legend.key=element_rect(fill = NA)) #This removes the boxes around the points 
ggAB
```

However, when I do this... I get this: 
[image]

The datapoints are plotted great (phew!), but why does it make the points bigger for my town names? I can't seem to get it to just keep the abundance for my 'n' number datapoints... It also doesn't put an automatic legend on (as ggplot usually does), even when I try and put one in manually using the scale_discrete function.

I thought it might be something to do with the fact that I use `gg + guides(size=FALSE)` in the first part, but even when taking that out it doesn't work, but adds in an annoying legend for my town datapoints.

Any ideas?

Comment: If you want to get lon and lat for the cities, you can use `geocode` in the `ggmap` package. Then, you can avoid manual works.

Comment: @jazzurro ooh thanks - will give that a go now!

Comment: Try this: `cities <- c("Salaverry", "Chimbote", "Callao", "Ilo"); locations <- geocode(cities)`

Comment: @jazzurro thanks! Is there a shortcut to then plot these points or is it just a case of copy and pasting them into my above code?

Comment: I was actually revising your code in my answer. I am happy to provide a code later. Once I post it as a complementary answer, I will let you know. No time now.

Comment: I added supplementary information for you. Please have a look. Hope this will give you some additional ideas.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that in the code where you add the towns, you have put the `size` inside the `aes`. Therefore it also gets transformed when you call `scale_size(name='Sharks per line', range = c(5,9))`. Just use `size` outside the `aes`:

```
gg <- gg + geom_point(aes(x=-78.981885, y=-8.229354), size=3) +
  annotate("text", label='Salaverry', size=4, x=-77.2, y=-8.229354) +
  geom_point(aes(x=-71.345838, y=-17.644347), size=3) +
  annotate("text", x=-70.545838, y=-17.644347, label = 'Ilo', size=4) +
  geom_point(aes(x=-77.142375, y=-12.047544), size=3) +
  annotate("text", x=-75.9, y=-12.047544, label = 'Callao', size=4) +
  geom_point(aes(x=-78.610677, y=-9.074166), size=3) +
  annotate("text", x=-76.9, y=-9.074166, label = 'Chimbote', size=4)
```

Comment: Now works perfectly, knew it had to be something really simple on my part! Thanks alot :)

Comment: @shadow: what about the case where size is based on a column variable? In my particular case, taking size outside of aes makes it meaningless and leaving it inside the aes seems to override my previous geom_point legend.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to @shadow's answer, I'd like to leave the following for the OP as supplementary information. This comes from the chat with the OP. If you want to avoid using `annotate`, you can use `geocode` in the `ggmap` package. Here, I added some from my answer to the previous question of the OP, and I combined/modified the OP's code. One change is that I used `alpha` so that you can see red/pink points in the ocean. One note is that the positions of the city names are not perfect; the further you go down south in the map, the more you see gaps between points and city names. This could be due to something to do with map projection. According to Wiki, googlemap is using something close to marcator, but not exact the same. This could be the reason. Some GIS experts here would be able to provide more information.

```
library(ggmap)
library(mapdata)
library(ggplot2)

# Get Peru map
Peru <- get_map(location = "Peru", zoom = 5, maptype="satellite") 

# This is the layer I wish to put over the top
coast_map <- fortify(map("worldHires", fill = TRUE, plot = FALSE)) 

# Subset data for Peru
peru.coast <- subset(coast_map, region == "Peru")

### Get lon and lat using geocode() in the ggmap package and crate a data frame
cities <- c("Salaverry", "Chimbote", "Callao", "Ilo")
locations <- geocode(cities)
locations$city <- cities
locations2 <- transform(locations, lon2 = lon + 1.1) # This is for text position


ggmap(Peru) +
geom_map(data = peru.coast, map = peru.coast, aes(x = long, y = lat, map_id = region),
         fill="gray", color="black") +
geom_point(data = locations2, aes(x = lon, y = lat, color = city), size = 4) +
geom_text(data = locations2, aes(x = lon2, y = lat, label = city), size = 3) +
scale_color_manual(values = rep(c("black"), times = 4)) + 
geom_point(data = newdata, aes(Set.Lon, Set.Lat, size = n), colour = "red", alpha = 0.5) +
scale_size(name = "Sharks per line", range = c(5,9)) +
xlim(-86, -70) +
ylim(-20, -4) + 
labs(x = "Longitude", y = "Latitude") +
coord_map("mercator") +
guides(colour=FALSE) +
theme(legend.key=element_rect(fill = NA))
```

[image]

Comment: @CDav I was not sure if you wanted this legend. But, I left it. If you do not want it, let me know. I will remove it.

Comment: Aha - This is SO much easier than my manual way! And I did want the legend - perfect thankyou!